# Can I reuse a while statements condition inside the loop without breaking it?

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

for example, im wanting to:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `1_cart_items` WHERE `cart_id`=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$cartid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while ($r=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
  {
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `new` (`field1`,`field2`) VALUES(`value1`,`value2`)");
     $stmt->bindValue(1,$r['value1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(2,$r['value2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Would I overwrite the $stmt variable or would this work? 
if not, then would makeing a new variable for it, and would unsetting that variable after close the connection too?

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop to begin with? It looks like you are selecting a single row.

Comment: Im using to to take rows in a temporary table and taking it to the complete table before deleting it, fetchAll should fetch all rows.

Comment: First, it doesn't look like you are fetching many rows, unless you have many cart items with the same id. Second, you probably don't need to write code to do this because MySql has [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: and to answer your question, yes, you would be overwriting your variable.

Comment: `while` does not add a new scope, you would be overwriting the `$stmt` variable.

Comment: In this case, id is not the primary key, but the primary key of the users cart, selecting all items with thier carts id. imagine id more as `cart_id` and its primary key to be something like `i`.